# Search for multiple objects within an ObservableCollection with a certain property

Tags: c#, linq

I have an `ObservableCollection` containing my items. Using the `Find()` method, I search for an object within the `ObservableCollection`, looking for it by date of insertion. Whenever I do the search, whether the object is found or not, I keep searching the list with `Datetime.Now.Date.AddDays(1)`.

```
var DtIndietro = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-15);
while(DtIndietro != DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1))
{
        try
       {
           var Find = note.Where(x => x.Dt.Date == DtIndietro).FirstOrDefault();
        
           DtIndietro = DtIndietro.AddDays(1);
    
        }
         catch
         {//something}
}
```

However, I would like that when he finds the object, he would continue the search anyway in order to understand if there were more than one with the same date of insertion. Is there any way?

Comment: note that this is a basic C# question and has nothing specific to do with Xamarin Forms or XAML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `FirstOrDefault` will, as the name implies, only return a single object

```
var Find = note.Where(x => x.Dt.Date == DtIndietro).FirstOrDefault();
```

if you leave that off you will get **ALL** matches

```
var FindAll = note.Where(x => x.Dt.Date == DtIndietro);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the where statement to

`note.Where(x => x.Dt.Date >= DtIndietro && x.Dt.Date < DtIndietro.AddDays(1))` to select all items on that day.

Answer (score 0):

To find all objects you have to use  ToList()  instead of FirstOrDefault():

```
....
var foundItems = note.Where(x => x.Dt.Date == DtIndietro).ToList();
....
```